# ReactJS when grabbing element around grid nodes are disapearing

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to move this gree node around my grid but when i move it last node in first line disapears.

Here is my code:

```
const onDrop = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.id)
        let data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

    const onDragStart = (e) => {
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
    }

    const onDragOver = (e) => {
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
    }

    return (
        <div
            onDrop={(e) => (onDrop(e))}
            onDragOver={(e) => (onDragOver(e))}
        >
            <div
                id={`${row}-${col}`}
                className={`node ${classes}`}
                draggable={draggAble}
                onDragStart={(e) => {
                    if (draggAble) {
                        onDragStart(e)
                    } else {
                        e.preventDefault()
                    }
                }}
            />
        </div>
    )
```

And this whole div is in another div with this code.

```
<div className="Grid" onDrop={(e) => (onDrop(e))} onDragOver={(e) => (onDragOver(e))}>
```

Here's link to my fiddle with snippet https://jsfiddle.net/Efiqqe/2tjs4v3f/1/

Each of this codes are in different components

Do you have any tips how to make the last node stop disapearing?

Thank you for your answers and I'm sorry if this post is not enough clear.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Comment: I added link to fiddle with working snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You move the child of `0-0` every time so you must add that in the first box.

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'temp-0-0';
div.className = 'node';
div.draggable = false;
if(!document.getElementById('temp-0-0')) {
    document.getElementById('node-0-0').appendChild(div);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gupay0rc/2/

Comment: Oh i see nice thank you very much. Can i use the same approach for the end node?